# How to reset bricks in 2D Canvas game

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I'm new to Javascript, so this might be an easy fix, but I can't figure out a way to reset the bricks inside the canvas. I'm using the function `redraw()` Full Code is at https://codepen.io/Jacob-Bruce/pen/mQgbXa

I've tried re-calling the `drawBricks` but I realize now I need to get the array to work.

```
// brick layout
var bricks = [];
for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}
// draw bricks
function drawBricks() {
  for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}
// redraw function -- used to reset when selecting mode
function redraw() {
  score = 0
  x = canvas.width/2;
  y = canvas.height-30;
  paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2
  // find how to make bricks reappear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  collisionDetection();
}
```

I want the bricks to reappear and completely reset the game, but it currently just resets the ball and paddle.

Comment: You could put your brick layout code in a function (leave var bricks outside). Then call this function to reset the bricks. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not sure what you meant, can you please clarify? Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this..

```
// brick layout
var bricks = [];
for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}
```

Change to

```
// brick layout
var bricks = [];
function resetBricks() {
    for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
      bricks[c] = [];
      for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
      }
   }
}
resetBricks();
```

Then call resetBricks() in your code when you want to..